# Optimize code to handle large chunks of data

Tags: python

I have the following code:

```
import json


data_sample = [{
"name":"John",
"age":30,
"cars":[ {
"temp":{
"sum":"20",
"for":12,
}
,
"id":30,
"element":[ {"model":"Taurus1", "doors":{"id":"1", "id2":101}}, {"model":"T1", "doors":{"id":"2", "id2":12}},  {"model":"As", "doors":{"id":"Mo", "id2":4}} ]
}, {
"temp":{
"sum":"10",
"for":12,
}
,
"id":31,
"element":[ {"model":"Taurus2", "doors":{"id":"2", "id2":102}}, {"model":"T2", "doors":{"id":"5", "id2":12}},  {"model":"Thing", "doors":{"id":"Fo", "id2":4}} ]
}, {
"temp":{
"sum":"20",
"for":10,
}
,
"id":32,
"element":[ {"model":"Taurus3", "doors":{"id":"3", "id2":103}}, {"model":"T3", "doors":{"id":"15", "id2":62}},  {"model":"By", "doors":{"id":"Log", "id2":4}} ]
} ]
}]

def flat_list(z):
    x = []
    for i, data_obj in enumerate(z):
        if type(data_obj) is dict or type(data_obj) is list:
            x.extend([flatten_data(data_obj)])
        else:
            x.extend([data_obj])
    return x


def flatten_data(y):
    out = {}
    def flatten(x, name=''):
            if type(x) is dict:
                for a in x:
                    flatten(x[a], name + a + '_')
            elif type(x) is list:
                out[name[:-1]] = flat_list(x)
            else:
                out[name[:-1]] = x
    flatten(y)
    return out

def generatejson(response2):

    # response 2 is [(first data set), (second data set)]  convert it to dictionary {0: (first data set), 1: (second data set)}
    sample_object = {i: data_response for i, data_response in enumerate(response2)}
    flat = {k: flatten_data(v) for k, v in sample_object.items()}
    return json.dumps(flat, sort_keys=True)

print generatejson(data_sample)
```

This code takes data from the following format:

```
[(first data set), (second data set)]
```

and begin to look for nesting dicts. If nesting dict is detected the code flats it to the parent level.

For example the code detects this:

[image]

`doors` is nested dict so it converts it to:

[image]

Note that it doesn't change the lists/arrays. They are not being flattened.

**My issue:**

On small amount of data the code works great however handling large amount of sets (1000+) the performance is very low... And sometimes even crash.

How can I improve and optimize the performance of this code?

The `data_sample` contains only 1 data set (I assume that's enough for checking).

Comment: Have you looked at [generators](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) for processing your data? They tend to use much less memory because they only work on a single data set at once.

Comment: @MatthewDaly It seems great but I'm not sure how I can implement it here? I'm using recursion in my code

Comment: A quick Google suggests it's possible - maybe do that and take a look at a few of the examples for ideas

Comment: @MatthewDaly If I get it right the bottom line is that it uses the same idea of iterators... I'm already using iterator in my generatejson function. I think the "expensive" part of my code is the recursion.. and I don't see how it's possible to convert it to what you suggested.

Comment: From your sample it looks like the top-level element is an array. So you can process each item seperately (using your recursive function) and output them. I'm assuming the crash is coming because you are running out of memory, trying to load all JSON elements into the program at once (for the eventual `json.dumps` at the end).

Comment: @Hitobat But this is what it does...   flat = {k: flatten_data(v) for k, v in sample_object.items()} takes one data set at a time...